# Prepare form with multiple product options for Paypal

Tags: php, shopping-cart, paypal, paypal-ipn

How can I prepare the option selection in the form to be sent to paypal?

I have tried,

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Book 1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="0.10" />

    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="option_name1" value="sizes">

    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Large"/>
...
```

or

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Book 1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="0.10" />

    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="sizes">

    <input type="hidden" name="os0" value="Large"/>
```

But I **can't** get any **option data** returned from `$_POST`

Besides, what if I have multiple products with different options, then how do I prepare the form?

For instance, **product 1** has the size **small** as the selection, while **product 2** has the size **large** as the selection. I assume that it could be like this?

```
    ....      

    <input type="hidden" name="option_name1" value="sizes">

    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Large"/>

    ....

    <input type="hidden" name="option_name1" value="sizes">

    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Small"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an unique name for each product,
if you want to get back the post value in PHP
suc as :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="option_name[$id1]" value="sizes">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select[$id1]" value="Large"/>
...
<input type="hidden" name="option_name[$id2]" value="sizes">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select[$id2]" value="Large"/>
```

You can also use `option_name[]`,
but this only return an indexed array in the `$_POST`

Also, why are you using hidden for option?
This is my understanding of option :-

```
<select name="sizes[$id1]">
 <option value="Large">Large</option>
 <option value="Large">Small</option>
</select>
...
<select name="sizes[$id2]">
 <option value="Large">Large</option>
 <option value="Large">Small</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I have misunderstood the option used in paypal. I should use IDs instead for my need. Thanks!